# How to find the offset and scaling factor using Python

Tags: python-3.x, curve-fitting

I have a data set generated from a sensor that gives the pressure over a period of time at a specific location. The sensor I'm using is low-cost not research graded. I have access to the data set from a research sensor and there's a correlation between my data set and the research-graded one. However, there's also a large offset and scaling. I would like to know if it's possible to use Python to fit my data set to the research-graded data set by determining the offset and scaling factor because the two data sets have similar shape the only difference is the offset and factor.

Thanks

Comment: Please post your input data, code and an example of what your outcome should be. See also [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for a simple scaling factor,

```py
def getScalingFactor(data1,data2,order=2):
    return np.linalg.norm(data1,order) / np.linalg.norm(data2,order) 

# For example, if your data is 
def f(x):
   return x**2;
x = np.arange(-5,6)

# y1 is your sensor data
y1 = f(x)       

# y2 is your 'research-graded' sensor data having a simple scale with respect to y1
y2 = f(x) * 2.  # 2.0 is your example scale

# You would expect `getScalingFactor` to return 2.0 
out_scale = getScalingFactor(y2,y1,order=2)
```

As you have explicitly mentioned about using Python, I have used [numpy.linalg.norm](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) to calculate the norms.